# Only allow certain IP's to access website, EXCEPT a specific URL (open to any IP)

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm aware of the below in `.htaccess` which only allows a certain IP to access a website:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

But I want to extend this to allow any IP to access a specific URL (i.e. www.mywebsite.com/any).

So my IP can access the whole website, but my friend's IP can only access a specific URL. It doesn't need forwarding to.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone in a similar situation, here's the code I used which works:

```
<Files "">
Order allow,deny
allow from 192.168.0.1
</Files>

<Files "any">
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>
```

Comment: Where did you find this solution? Can you post a link to the solution page?

Comment: I didn't find it, I made it :) I was researching "Location" and learned it's not something which can be used in the .htaccess file, but "Files" can. So I experimented a little and got it working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mod-rewrite instead of Allow/deny directives :

```
RewriteEngine on

#redirect client to /any if not my ip address
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^YourIP$
RewriteRule !any /any [L,R]
```

This will redirect all other ip address except **yourIP** to **/any** .

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) However I don't want users to be forwarded to /any if they're not my IP. I've found my solution though (see my answer below).

Answer (score -1):

"Location /" is the root of your url (mysite.com), only the specific ip (192.168.0.1o for example) has access and Location /all is part of the site that everyone das access (mysite.com/all).

```
<Location />
Order Allow,deny
Allow from myIP #Allow from 192.168.0.10
</Location>

<Location /all> 
Order Allow,deny
Allow from all
</Location>
```

Easy peasy If you read the [doc's](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html#order)

Comment: Forgive me, I'm not too clued up on htaccess. Where would I input my IP & the URL to exclude into your code?

Comment: What do you understand as different url? Are http://example1.com and http://example2.com or http://example.com/ABC and http://example.com/123 ?

Comment: Let's say the site is on www.mysite.com < That URL should be locked down to a certain IP. www.mysite.com/all < That URL should be allowed from any IP. Does that make sense?

Comment: I appreciate your help Joao, however that now gives me  an Internal Server Error...

Comment: Iforget to close the location tag. If this didin't help, post the log

Comment: [alert] /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/subdomain.mysite.com/.htaccess: <Location not allowed here, referer: https://subdomain.mysite.com/